# Best way to say "human aspect" or "human element" in one word?

Tags: synonyms, syntactic-analysis

My example is as follows:

"The piece of art had a sort of merit, normalcy, and _______."

Like the quality of being made by a human, rather than the machine. I best describe it as the difference between a song produced with an electronic drum track as opposed to a human drummer. The human drummer has a sort of inconsistency and charm that only an imperfect human can.

I'd rather stick with one word, because going from one word adjectives to a two word one seems imbalanced and clumsy.

I also don't like the word humanity here because it almost personifies the piece of art, rather than describing it was made by a human.

Comment: I think you've eliminated the word that best fits.

Comment: I like *craftsmanship* or *soulfulness*.

Comment: *Humanness* is the less elegant alternative for *humanity*. Other relevant terms are multi-word, e.g. *human touch*.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the rejection of **humanity**

"The piece of art had a sort of merit, normalcy, and humanity."

> **humanity** NOUN
> 2. Humaneness; benevolence.
> ‘It's a good story, told with humor, humanity, and compassion.’
> [LEXICO](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/humanity)

Answer (score 0):

**Organicity** might fit, as it is an adjective describing something "related to or derived from living organisms". There are some limitations in that it could describe the style of art rather than how it was actually made, but then again, you could feasibly program a machine to recreate any piece of human-made art. There's also no link to humans specifically, as even a cat with paint on its paws could walk across a canvas and create art with some level of organicity. But overall, I think this captures some aspects of what you're looking for, describing something that does not exhibit machine-level precision of lines, angles, etc., but has a more natural and organic quality.

Answer (score 0):

Yoself Baskin's suggestions in a comment led me to:

> The piece of art had a sort of merit, normalcy, and **workmanship**.

It's fairly neutral in not ascribing *specific* (human) attributes:

**workmanship** (n.)

> *Workmanship* is the skill with which something is made and which
> affects the appearance and quality of the finished object.
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/workmanship)

> The degree of skill with which a product is made or a job done.
>
> *The company is opening showrooms all over the world and the standard of workmanship here is second to none.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/workmanship)

---

> It is noticeable, however, that throughout there seems not only a want
> of direction but also of feeling, the **workmanship** is mechanical
> and deficient in that **human touch** which was afterwards to be
> supplied so bountifully under the inspiration and personal guidance of
> the Mughuls. [Percy Brown; *Indian Architecture (The Islamic
> Period)*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Indian_Architecture_The_Islamic_Period/YCF9CgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=workmanship%20human%20touch&pg=PT377&printsec=frontcover) (2013)

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to simply use the adjective "human" and change the structure of the sentence so that it relies on adjectives as opposed to nouns.

The piece of art felt normal, meritable, and human.

Thank you so much for you guys' suggestions!

Comment: I'm glad you found something you like, but I'd argue that this version goes even farther toward making it sound like you're personifying the work. If your emphasis is to contrast something made a single person's creative process to something produced by artificial or mechanized means, and adjectives are ok, what about "hand-made"?

Comment: *Meritable* is an abnormal word. Try *meritorious*.